# Codigo VBA se detiene sin motivo aparente

Tags: vba

Tengo una macro (VBA) que se ejecuta automáticamente cuando ocurre un evento. Lleva más de un año funcionando correctamente. Sin ninguna razón que yo alcance a comprender, desde hace un rato la macro se ejecuta con el evento pero se detiene en una línea concreta. Me abre el editor de VBA como cuando ocurre un error de código pero no me aparece ningún error, de echo, si le doy a Continuar(F5) la macro continua sin problemas y se ejecuta todo correctamente. 
Se comporta exactamente igual que como si se tratara de un 'Stop'.

Este 'error' ocurre siempre en la misma línea (es una llamada a otra macro vba). Tiene la siguiente forma:

```
Variable = Funcion("cadena")
```

He reiniciado ya el PC dos veces y no se arregla solo.

¿Le ha pasado esto a alguien alguna vez? ¿sabe alguien como corregir este error fantasma?

Siento no poder compartir el código, ya que es del trabajo y me lo impide la política de seguridad. Pero si alguien necesita más información, acerca de las operaciones que realiza la macro, intentaré proporcionarla hasta la medida de lo possible.

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Has depurado el código de la función? Sería interesante saber en que punto se para, si es antes de entrar en ella, si es en algún punto intermedio o si es al devolver el valor a la variable. Si se para en medio de la función intenta descubrir en que línea exacta.

Comment: @Fly la macro se para justo antes de entrar en la función. Si en ese momento presiono 'Paso a paso (F8)' entra en la función

Comment: Intenta fijarte en el valor que puedan tomar tus variables locales con las que interactua tu funcion a ver si con ello aclaras algo o ves algo que no debiera estar ahi. Desde luego sin nada de código es dificil ayudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues lamento las molestias a todos los interesados, sobre todo a @Fly y @Valentín. No se exactamente que estaría pasando pero ya no pasa.......

Lo que he hecho ha sido cambiar la función por su resultado para que no tuviera que entrar en dicha función. De esa forma ha dejado de fallar. Luego he vuelto a dejar el código como al principio, es decir, llamando a esa función y mágicamente ha vuelto a funcionar bien como antes.

He cambiado

```
Variable = Funcion("cadena")
```

por

```
Variable = "resultado de la función"
```

he ejecutado el evento que inicia la macro y luego he vuelto a cambiar el código a lo inicial:

```
Variable = Funcion("cadena")
```

Es un misterio para mi lo que ha ocurrido pero parece que ya funciona bien de nuevo.

De todas formas se me ocurre una posible explicación. Para ello voy a explicar por encima como estaba estructurada la macro:

1º un evento de correo de entrada de outlook ejecuta un script vbs

2º el script vbs ejecuta una macro alojada en un accdb

3º el accdb realiza operaciones entre la que se encontraba la función que daba problemas.

Esta mañana, antes de que comenzara el error, estuve depurando el código y puse varias veces un break point justamente dentro de esa función. De alguna forma la macro almacenó que yo estaba parando la macro en ese punto de manera que no ha vuelto a funcionar correctamente hasta que no he modificado el código para "resetear la memoria".

Lo dicho, un misterio. Muchas gracias a todos